# Using a helper on options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a select with all months of the year as numbers (1,2,3...12) and a method which converts the number of the month to its name. Ex: (1->January, 2->February...)

I'd like to use it on a `select`, showing the name of the month instead of the number.

My question is, how do I generate a select passing this method to my `options_for_select` below?

```
<div class="ls-custom-select">
  <%=
    form.select(
        :month,
        options_for_select((1..12), selected: @current_month),
        {},
        { class: "ls-select" }
      )
  %>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get seperate text and values by using an array of pairs:

```
options_for_select([["January", 1], ["February", 2]])
# => <option value="1">January</option>
# => <option value="2">February</option>
```

You can get localized month names by using the Rails 18n module:

```
(1..12).to_a.zip(I18n.t("date.month_names").drop(1))
# => [[1, "January"], [2, "February"], [3, "March"], [4, "April"], [5, "May"], [6, "June"], [7, "July"], [8, "August"], [9, "September"], [10, "October"], [11, "November"], [12, "December"]]
```

`.zip` merges two arrays together into pairs. `.drop(1)` is needed since the first element in the month_names array is nil (there is no month 0).

```
<div class="ls-custom-select">
  <%=
    form.select(
        :month,
        options_for_select(
          (1..12).to_a.zip(I18n.t("date.month_names").drop(1),
          @current_month # selected
        )
        {},
        { class: "ls-select" }
    )
  %>
</div>
```

You don't need to write a method to get month names. Use `I18n.t("date.month_names")[number]`. Or if localization is not important use `Date::MONTHNAMES[number]`.

Comment: You don't need to write a method to get month names. Use `I18n.t("date.month_names")[number]`.

Comment: Nice max! Your solution solved my doubts :). I just changed a bit to fit better. Thanks again! Here it is :)

<%=
          form.select(
            :month,
            options_for_select(
              I18n.t("date.month_names").zip((1..12)),
              selected: @current_month
            ),
            {},
            { class: "ls-select" }
          )
        %>

Comment: One more question, is there a problem if I remove the first element (the nil one?)